# C++, name collision across different namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am baffled by the following name collision:

```
namespace mp2 {

boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_range<M>
slice(M& m, const R1& r1, const R2& r2) {
    namespace ublas = boost::numeric::ublas;
    ublas::range r1_(r1.begin(), r1.end()), r2_(r2.begin(), r2.end());
    return ublas::matrix_range<M>(m, r1_, r2_);
}

double energy(const Wavefunction &wf) {
    const Wavefunction::matrix& C = wf.coefficients();
    int No = wf.occupied().size();

    foreach (const Basis::MappedShell& P, basis.shells()) {
        slice(C, range(No), range(P));
```

the error from g++4.4 is

```
 7 In file included from mp2.cpp:1:
 8 /usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/fwd.hpp: In function âdouble mp2::energy(const Wavefunction&)â:
 9 /usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/fwd.hpp:32: error: âboost::numeric::ublas::sliceâ is not a function,
10 ../../src/mp2/energy.hpp:98: error:   conflict with âtemplate<class M, class R1, class R2> boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_range<M> mp2::slice(M&, const R1&, const R2&)â
11 ../../src/mp2/energy.hpp:123: error:   in call to âsliceâ
12 /usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/fwd.hpp:32: error: âboost::numeric::ublas::sliceâ is not a function,
13 ../../src/mp2/energy.hpp:98: error:   conflict with âtemplate<class M, class R1, class R2> boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_range<M> mp2::slice(M&, const R1&, const R2&)â
14 ../../src/mp2/energy.hpp:129: error:   in call to âsliceâ
15 make: *** [mp2.lo] Error 1
```

ublas segment is

```
namespace boost { namespace numeric { namespace ublas {
    typedef basic_slice<> slice;
```

why is slice in ublas collides with slice in mp2?
I and fairly certain there is no `using namespace ublas` in the code and in includes.

thank you

Comment: sorry, there were some extraneous compiler messages removed

Comment: do you have a using statement anywhere?

Comment: @Dav no, I have not found any.  I look through ublas includes, they seemed to be okay as well

Answer (score 2):

I think there is [argument-dependent lookup](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/030.htm) going on.

```
slice(C, range(No), range(P));
```

Two `range` arguments are seemingly from `boost::numeric::ublas` (probably imported with `using boost::numeric::ublas::range;`), so the compiler considers names form this namespace, which includes `slice` type in it.